# Why does $z=(-i)^{1/2}$ imply $z=e^{(-\pi/2+2n\pi)i}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$z $ is a complex number; why does $z=-i^{1/2}$ imply $z=e^{(-\pi/2+2n\pi)i}$?

In my textbook this is written without explanation; why is this true?
(It says $z^2=-i=exp(i(-\pi/2+2n\pi))$)

Comment: That's what I thought too actually, because somewhere else it says that $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$

Comment: For square root of complex numbers you need to pick a "branch" since there is always two numbers which can have the same square.

Comment: sorry what does that mean?

Comment: is $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$ just a property to be memorized? I don't see why it is true

Comment: Actually I found a formula that says $z^n=e^nlog(z)$, I'm guessing that is how it's derived

Comment: You can see it if you do the euler identities $re^{bi} = r(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))$

Comment: That's how you see it will have the period with $2\pi$ also. Since cos and sine have that period.

Comment: So is $z^2=-i=e^{-i\pi/4}$ incorrect?

Comment: sorry I was misreading something. Thanks for the help

Comment: How do you define $z^{1/2}$ when $z$ is a complex number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (principal branch) of the logarithm of a complex number $z\ne0$ is
$$
\log z=\log|z|+i\arg z
$$
where $\arg$ is the principal branch of the argument, $-\pi<\arg z\le\pi$. Then
$$
z=e^{\log z+2k\pi i},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
If $z\ne0$, $a$ are complex numbers, then
$$
z^a=e^{a(\log z+2k\pi i)}.
$$
We have $|-i|=1$, $\arg(-i)=-\pi/2$ and $\log(-i)=-i\,\pi/2$. Then
$$
(-i)^{1/2}=e^{\log(-i)/2}=e^{(-i\pi/2+2k\pi i)/2}=e^{-i\pi/4+k\pi i},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: thank you,merci! very clear. just to go a step further; why is $e^{-i\pi/4+ki\pi}=(1-i)/\sqrt{2}$? I do not see why the $\sqrt{2}$ is there.

Comment: Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$.

Answer (score 0):

Eulers formula states that:
$$
\exp{\left(i\,x\right)} = \cos{(x)} + i\,\sin{(x)}
$$
It can be proven by using the taylor expansion of $\exp(i\,x)$ :
$$
1 + ix + \frac{(ix)^2}{2!} + \frac{(ix)^3}{3!} + \frac{(ix)^4}{4!} + ...\\
= \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - ...\right) + i\,\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - ...\right)\\
= \cos{(x)} + i\,\sin{(x)}
$$
now using this:
$$
\exp{\left((-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\,n\pi)\,i\right)} = \cos{(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\,n\pi)} + i\,\sin{(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\,n\pi)}\\
= \cos{(-\frac{\pi}{2})} + i\,\sin{(-\frac{\pi}{2})}\\
= -i \ne -\sqrt{i}
$$
So I would say it should either be $ z = (-1)^{1/2}$ or it is simply wrong.

Comment: Very helpful thank you